# Excel VBA Collections / coll.Count - dynamic

Tags: excel, vba, collections

I have a query on collections. I am trying to create some code that will access my collections dynamically. But I am running into the following troubles.

**Example**

I have created a collection and performed the following`Debug.Print Backpack_O.Count`. The result was `3` - this was expected.

However, when I try and do this dynamically `Debug.Print wks_GM2.Range("A" & b) & "_" & wks_GM2.Range("D" & b) & ".Count"` my result is `Backpack_O.Count` - not the desired output.

The reason why I need this dynamically is so I can substituate this into a `For` loop. As an example:

```
For i = 1 To wks_GM2.Range("A" & b) & "_" & wks_GM2.Range("D" & b) & ".Count"
```

I have tried wrapping this in `CLng` `CStr` etc but I'm coming up blank. Can anyone help me resolve this...

Cheers!!!

Comment: You might try .Range("A"  & b & ":D" & b).cells.count. debug.print the concatenation to make sure you don't need to wrap the'b' in Cstr.

Comment: This doesnt work

Comment: Sorry.  Should have been .Range("A" & b, "D" & b).Cells.Count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to create a collection of collections, with the collection names as the keys. For example:

```
Dim Backpack_0 As New Collection
Dim Backpack_1 As New Collection
...

Dim masterCollection As New Collection
masterCollection.Add Item:=Backpack_0, Key:="Backpack_0"
masterCollection.Add Item:=Backpack_1, Key:="Backpack_1"
...
```

Now you can refer to the individual collections dynamically by building up the key from your worksheet:

```
Dim collectionName as String
collectionName = wks_GM2.Range("A" & b).Value & "_" & wks_GM2.Range("D" & b).Value

For i = 1 to masterCollection(collectionName).Count
```

Comment: For reference - if anyone is viewing this, I used the letter 'O', where as @BigBen used the numeral '0'.. Substitute and it works